# Update value in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am new in pyhton, I have a dictionary like below containing duplicate keys

```
         dicts = {
            'name': name,
            'phone': phone,
            'key_ids': [
                # line one.
                (0, 0, {
                    'key1': value1,
                    'key2': value2,
                    
                }),
                # line two .
                (0, 0, {
                    'key1': value1,
                    'key3': value2,
     }),
            ],
        }
```

I want to replace key1 value in the line two as commented, when I use below code its replace key1 in the two line, how to access key1 in line two only?

```
          for line in dicts[0]['line_ids']:
             line[2]['key1'] = new_key
```

Comment: Don't use a loop? `dicts[0]['line_ids'][1][2]['key1'] = new_key`

Comment: There is no key `0` in `dicts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
dicts['key_ids'][1][2]['key1'] = new_key
```

this will first get key_ids then access the second line with the index and then the key1 can be given a new value.
hope this answers your question